# How to post url and encode it in JAVA?

Tags: java, url, urlencode

After i do googling and do some experiments,I am still confused how to post URL and encode it in one method directly. There is an additional problem for me, the process of encoding must be replaced with `%20`.

Appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you see this> http://developers.sun.com/mobility/midp/ttips/HTTPPost/

Comment: or this? http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.net/post.html

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `java.net.*` classes for that?
Particulary, you're interested in `java.net.UrlEncoder` and `java.net.UrlDecoder`.
Enjoy =)

Comment: can you give me explanation about that?how to implement it in code?

Comment: Use static methods of those classes. - UrlEncoder.Encode("your_url_string", "UTF-8"), same with UrlDecoder.Decode(...)

Comment: oke thanks..but,i mean i want to encode query with %20.i am still confused how to implement it. i am sorry wasting your time.

Comment: These classes are EXACTLY what you need. They should deal with %** symbols - that's 100% true.